# Grouping of buttons for toggling in iOS (SWIFT or Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this case:[image]

4 Buttons for the Availability and Another 4 Buttons for bedrooms. I want the user to be able to toggle between the buttons for each category "Availability and Bedrooms" without affecting each other. To cut it short, i want the buttons of Availability to be mutually exclusive from Bedrooms. And of course only one button can be chosen for each category.

So technically speaking, Can i group number of buttons so every time the user touches a button the app checks the group name to know which buttons will be de-selected ?

Thank you

Comment: you could create outlet collections, and would work with such collections to select or deselect the buttons in a certain collection at the same time; but that is just common sense, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @holex that really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out. So i am answering that for anyone who's tackling the same problem.

I have used Both, Outlet Collection and Tags. I used tags with same number for grouping. And used the Outlet collection to loop on all buttons which are related to the chosen tag.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you researched using tags for viewing and maybe variables for grouping?

```
var button = 0 //Where 0, 1 and 2 would represent no press, on and off?
```

And then having situations occur based on the state of the button?

Comment: Can Several buttons have the same tag ?